# Regular Expressions: how to interpret *?

Tags: regex, operators

I know what `*` is and what `?` is.

However, I don't understand what `*?` is. I know it's used to make the "greedy" * operator a lazy one, but still, how does that read if `*` is `zero or more times` and `?` is `one or one time`.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I underline the fact that I know what `*`, `?`, `greedy` and `lazy` are.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: This time PHP. Other times JavaScript and ActionScript and sometimes others as well. How to know what engine they use and how that affects my RegExp Expressions?

Comment: mainly I wanted to know the language you were using.  Many languages interpret the regular expression portions differently so it's important to know the language when answering this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a trick that has been used to extend regexp syntax without adding more special characters. Of course saying "zero or one" after "zero or more" has no meaning... so the combination `*?` should be read as a single token meaning "zero or more - not greedy". In a similar way `+?` should be read as a single token meaning "one or more - not greedy".

Greedyness never changes what strings are matched and what are not matched, but it may change what is the match found. For example group 1 of `(AB*?)B+` matches `A` in `ABBBBB`, but group 1 of `(AB*)B+` matches `ABBBB` in the same string.

The question mark in "strange places" has been used also in other special combinations that are available in several regexp engines, for example:

```
(?=...)     zero-width positive lookahead assertion
(?!...)     zero-width negative lookahead assertion
(?:...)     non-tagging group
```

as you see they all start with `(?` where clearly the question mark couldn't mean "zero or one" (we're at the beginning of an expression, zero or one of what?).

Comment: Thank you, robot (6502). Just what I wanted to know, especially this part: `"zero or one" after "zero or more" has no meaning... so the combination *? should be read as a single token meaning "zero or more - not greedy"`.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is `zero or more times` and `?` is `zero or one times`, but `*?` is `zero or more times, not greedily`. It's its own entity.

Comment: Thank you, Viaken. If it wasn't for 6502's very complete answer, yours would have been it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the string  `AAABAAAAAAAAB` matching with `/.*B/` versus `/.*?B/`. The first finds the whole string (greedy) and the second stops with as few A's as possible.

(In a Perl or Java or PHP etc extraction this would matter; if you're just searching in vi, it stops at the first `A` either way.)

`?` by itself is match 0 or 1 times. But that's different from the `*?` usage.

(This is, basically, Perl-style regex. Some regexes might behave differently, but mostly like this.)

Here's a little Perl demo:

```
$a = "AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAB";

print " first: ";
print $1 if($a =~ /(.*B)/);

print "\nsecond: ";
print $1 if($a =~ /(.*?B)/);

print "\n";
```

Comment: Umm... Have you actually tested it?

Answer (score 1):

Read this - [Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

In your example, when the ? is used after the *, it is making the * lazy, so if you use the example in the above link:

This greedy regex - `<.*`>
given this string
"This is a `<EM`>first`</EM`> test"
would match
`<EM`>first`</EM`>
(It was greedy - it took the biggest (widest) match it could)

This lazy regex - <.*?>
given this string
"This is a `<EM`>first`</EM`> test"
would match
`<EM`>
(It was lazy - it took the smallest (most narrow) match it could)

Answer (score 0):

`*` means "match the expression before this `*` **any** amount of times (including zero)"

`?` means "match the expression before this `?` **zero or one** time"

Greedy vs. lazy means that the expression prefers to stop as soon as possible with matching, instead of getting the longest match as possible.

Whether or not `*?` means `*`, but then lazy, depends on your regex engine.